# Force function template/function overload for specific type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I've got a function

`foo(int, int, int, int/long long/_int64/double/long double/char *, int ONLY IF previous char * - otherwise unneeded)`

Problem is, char * implementation is different than the value types due to requiring a string copy. Yes, this is an interface to old code, so i cannot use std::string :/

Currently, I've got it as a template, and a function overload for char *, with the extra argument. However, all operations for the other types are also valid on char *, so if the caller forgets the last argument, the function silently matches the template instead, producing the wrong logic.

Is there any way I can force the usage of the overload/use default arguments in function templates/something that will allow for a different signature (extra argument) for a specific type without silently matching a lesser signature?

More:
No access to C++11 yet, but I'm open to see a suggestion using it to help push for adoption.
No boost, but same as above

I have also tried

`return_type foo(int,int,int,typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type & value2update)`

without any luck. It then claims that the call with a double & parameter fails to match.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "otherwise unneeded"? This should be implementable easily through overloading.

Comment: I assume the extra `int` is a length? Could you take a [StringPiece](http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/browse/re2/stringpiece.h) instead to avoid the need for special-casing entirely?

Comment: @Xeo, yeah I just wanted to avoid code duplication for each type so wanted to templatize the other types, which all share exactly the same code. @ Scott Lamb, yes, for sure that is a valid - and likely the best - option. However, this integration will happen in around 3000 places in the codebase, so having to add in the StringPiece creation logic in the calling code was something I would have liked to avoid. I was just hoping there was something I was doing wrong to force specialization - have to investigate Thomas' answer more thoroughly

Comment: If this is how you wanted to go, you could look into [clang tools](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTools.html) for automatic refactoring. I hear it's awesome for this kind of tedious change, though I've never tried it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the linker help you. Declare, but do not define, your function template and `char*` overload in a header:

```
template<typename T>
foo(int, int, int, T);
foo(int, int, int, char*, int);
```

In the implementation file (.cpp/.cc), implement both:

```
template<typename T>
foo(int, int, int, T) { ... }

foo(int, int, int, char*, int) { ... }
```

And explicitly instantiate versions for the types you want to accept:

```
template<>
foo(int, int, int, int);
template<>
foo(int, int, int, long long);
// etc.
```

---

If I'm understanding correctly, ScottLamb suggests something like this in the comments. Header:

```
foo(int, int, int, int);
foo(int, int, int, long long);
...
foo(int, int, int, char*, int);
```

Implementation file (.cpp/.cc):

```
namespace {
    template<typename T>
    foo_tmpl(int, int, int, T) { ... }
}

foo(int, int, int, int) { foo_tmpl(...); }
foo(int, int, int, long long) { foo_tmpl(...); }
....
foo(int, int, int, char*, int) { ... }
```

This is preferable from the perspective of someone using the header (they can see immediately which overloads are available) but takes slightly more work on the implementation side.

Comment: IMHO the header would be more straightforward/readable if you listed each supported overload. If the definition is non-trivial, you could delegate to a template function in an anonymous namespace in the implementation file to reduce duplication.

Comment: From the looks of it, this is the best answer. Just to be clear, are the explicit instantiations in the header or cpp file? @ScottLamb would you care to explain your comment? Are you saying the instantiations should be listed in the header as I just mentioned, and then define it in the cpp file? BTW this entire class is scoped in a namespace if that changes things

Comment: Updated with what I think he means.

Comment: @ScottLamb, Thomas, I've put in place the suggested format after the update. Thank you so much. As a quick note, my template function also makes use of a member function. For that reason I cannot wrap it in an anonymous namespace correct? I had to privately declare it in the header as well.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that you have to declare with the class (probably in the header) then.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper class `string_ref` that bundles the both parameters for you:

```
class string_ref {
  const char *str;
  std::size_t len;
public:
  string_ref(std::string const& s)
    : str(s.c_str()), len(s.size()) {}

  string_ref(const char *c, std::size_t len)
    : str(c), len(len) {}

  const char * c_str() const { return str; }
  std::size_t size() const { return len; }
};
```

And then

```
foo(int, int, int, int/long long/_int64/double/long double/const char*, [int])
```

Just add

```
foo(int, int, int, string_ref)
{
   foo(int, int, int, c_str(), size());
}
```

A `string_ref` can be created from a `const char*` and `int` with no overhead and both can be extracted easily for further passing to C functions.

(The naming `string_ref` is [not random](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3442.html).)

Comment: This is not safe! `std::string::c_str()` is only valid as long as the `string` object still exists and isn't modified.

Comment: I don't see a problem if this is used with care. `foo(..., string_ref(std::string("ok")))` for example should be fine.

Comment: I like this answer as it is sort of the way it *should* be done, i think - very close to just using std::string. In addition, I appreciate the comment on no overhead - that is of critical concern in this case, and in other situations, more elegant object-oriented solutions have been discarded for raw speed after profiling. Is it truly "no" overhead? I fail to see how the actual assignment assembler instructions are not generated for this string_ref object.